# Run projects in Java with the CodeRunner IDE on mac

Tags: java, macos, coderunner

Sorry for my level of English.

I have a problem with CodeRunner IDE that prevents me from using it correctly.

If I create an application with CodeRunner and run it, I have no problems, but if I save it to the hard disk I cannot run it again.

Once saved I always get this error:

> CodeRunner Warning: Could not find a main method in the file "Untitled.java". Please add a main method or run the file in your project containing your main method.
>   Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal The file “Untitled.java” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file..Untitled

It doesn't matter where you keep it or what name you put it on.

And if I open a Main.java file created with IntelliJ and run it it gives me an error. I get the same message:

> CodeRunner Warning: Could not find a main method in the file "Main.java". Please add a main method or run the file in your project containing your main method. Error: main class not found or loaded The file “Main.java” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file..Main

It could be something from Run Seting. Currently I have it like this:

> java -cp "$ {compiler%: *}" "$ {compiler # *:}"

As it came by default.

Could you help me?
Do you know why it gives me an error?
How to create a project with CodeRunner?

Thank you so much everyone,

Answer (score 0):

Check that names of your directories don't contains "special characters", CodeRunner only read & execute files in "English" routes... Happy code!

Answer (score 0):

`"${compiler%:*}"`: Remove the last colon (:) and all characters after it from the end of the variable compiler.

`"${compiler#*:}"`: Remove the first colon (:) and all characters before it from the beginning of the variable compiler

Suppose the `compiler` variable is `/path/to/libraries:./classes`
The command will be parsed as:
`java -cp "/path/to/libraries" "./classes"`

Change Run Setting to:

```
#java -cp "${compiler%:*}" "${compiler#*:}"
javac $filename
java "${filename%.*}"
```

And then the problem will be solved.